# PHP can't upload files to server?

Tags: php, file-upload

I have a php file that uploads images like jpegs and png onto a folder called uploads that is stored on the apache server and in the same location as the php file.

I have checked the code of both the HTML and the PHP and both seem to be perfectly fine, however whenever I try to upload a file I always get an error message and the file doesn't get uploaded.

It would be much appreciated if someone with more experience than me can look at my code and tell me why it is behaving in this manner.

Here is the HTML form:

```
<!--
To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
and open the template in the editor.
-->
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>Upload Your File</title>
</head>
<body>
    <?php
    // put your code here
    ?>

    <form enctype="multipart/form-data" method="post" action="fileHandler.php">
        Select File:
        <input name="uploaded_file" type="file"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the PHP file that is executed when the form is submitted:

```
<?php

/*
 * To change this template, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 * PHP file that uploads files and handles any errors that may occur
 * when the file is being uploaded. Then places that file into the 
 * "uploads" directory. File cannot work is no "uploads" directory is created in the
 * same directory as the function. 
 */

$fileName = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"];//the files name takes from the HTML form
$fileTmpLoc = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["tmp_name"];//file in the PHP tmp folder
$fileType = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["type"];//the type of file 
$fileSize = $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["size"];//file size in bytes
$fileErrorMsg = $FILES["uploaded_file"]["error"];//0 for false and 1 for true
$target_path = "uploads/" . basename( $_FILES["uploaded_file"]["name"]); 

echo "file name: $fileName </br> temp file location: $fileTmpLoc<br/> file type: $fileType<br/> file size: $fileSize<br/> file upload target: $target_path<br/> file error msg: $fileErrorMsg<br/>";

//START PHP Image Upload Error Handling---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    if(!$fileTmpLoc)//no file was chosen ie file = null
    {
        echo "ERROR: Please select a file before clicking submit button.";
        exit();
    }
    else
        if(!$fileSize > 16777215)//if file is > 16MB (Max size of MEDIUMBLOB)
        {
            echo "ERROR: Your file was larger than 16 Megabytes";

            unlink($fileTmpLoc);//remove the uploaded file from the PHP folder
            exit();
        }
        else
            if(!preg_match("/\.(gif|jpg|jpeg|png)$/i", $fileName))//this codition allows only the type of files listed to be uploaded
            {
                echo "ERROR: Your image was not .gif, .jpg, .jpeg or .png";
                unlink($fileTmpLoc);//remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder
                exit();
            }
            else
                if($fileErrorMsg == 1)//if file uploaded error key = 1 ie is true
                {
                    echo "ERROR: An error occured while processing the file. Please try again.";
                    exit();
                }


    //END PHP Image Upload Error Handling---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------


    //Place it into your "uploads" folder using the move_uploaded_file() function
    $moveResult = move_uploaded_file($fileTmpLoc, $target_path);

    //Check to make sure the result is true before continuing
    if($moveResult != true)
    {
        echo "ERROR: File not uploaded. Please Try again.";
        unlink($fileTmpLoc);//remove the uploaded file from the PHP temp folder

    }
    else
    {
        //Display to the page so you see what is happening 
        echo "The file named <strong>$fileName</strong> uploaded successfully.<br/><br/>";
        echo "It is <strong>$fileSize</strong> bytes.<br/><br/>";
        echo "It is a <strong>$fileType</strong> type of file.<br/><br/>";
        echo "The Error Message output for this upload is: $fileErrorMsg";
    }
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

make sure that the directory structure has write permissions.  You can check within php by using [is_writeable](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-writable.php).  By checking from within PHP you will also be making sure that the PHP user has write access.

Comment: Thanks the problem was that the permissions of the file weren't writeable after changing them it works totally fine now.

Answer (score 3):

Check the folder permissions on the server. If incorrect, you can modify your php.ini file.