# phpMailer file attachment not working, any advice?

Tags: php, phpmailer

I have an HTML form and I am using phpMailer. When completing the form and clicking submit all data entered in the text input fields etc work as expected. However, when I attach a file to the input type "file" when receiving the email no attachment is there.

Does anyone have any suggestions as to why the attachment is not attached?

FYI - at current, the site has no SSL certificate and the emails are going to the spam folder - could this be the issue?

I' am new to phpMailer and have been able to achieve the below by research.

**phpMailer()**

```
<?php

$file = $_POST['file'];

// more variables... 

$CustomerSignature = $_POST['q21'];
$Date = $_POST['q22'];
$filename = "./upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"./upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);

    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
    use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\SMTP;

    require 'phpMailer/src/Exception.php';
    require 'phpMailer/src/PHPMailer.php';
    require 'phpMailer/src/SMTP.php';
    require 'phpMailer/src/OAuth.php'; 

    $mail = new PHPMailer;
    $mail->isSMTP();
    $mail->SMTPDebug = 3;
    $mail->Host = 'smtp.hostinger.com';
    $mail->Port = 465;
    $mail->SMTPAuth = true;
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Username = '######';
    $mail->Password = '######';
    $mail->isHTML(true);
    $mail->setFrom('######', '######');
    $mail->addReplyTo('######', '######');
    $mail->addAddress('######', '######');
    $mail->addAddress('######');
    $mail->AddAttachment($filename);
    $mail->Subject = 'New Credit Application';
    $mail->Body = '<b>New Credit Application (Online)!</b></br>'
.'Trading Name: '.$TradingName.'</br>'
.'blah blah blah etc.'
.'Customer Signature: '.$CustomerSignature.'</br>'
.'Date: '.$Date.'</br>';
    if (!$mail->send()) {
        echo 'Mailer Error: ' . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    } else {
        echo 'The email message was sent.';
    }
?>
```

**HTML file attachment part:**

```
<form method="POST" action="testmail2.php" id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off">
                    <ol class="fs-fields">
                        
                        <li>
                            <label class="fs-field-label fs-anim-upper" for="file">Attachment</label>
                            <input class="fs-anim-lower" id="file" name="file" type="file" required/>
                        </li>
```

Comment: Enable all error level and display it. `$path` is undefined variable, I don't see it anywhere. Before go to send an email, make sure that the file is uploaded properly.

Comment: @vee , error log shows on first line, Could not access file:

Comment: @vee, i made some code changes, now the error is gone, the email is attaching a blank file named uplaod, and the logs show the following:


2021-12-13 12:28:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Transfer-Encoding: base64
2021-12-13 12:28:19 CLIENT -> SERVER: Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=upload

Comment: @Martin , 6.5.3 - the most up-to-date, I have only downloaded it today from GitHub

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Send File Attachment from Form Using phpMailer and PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11764156/send-file-attachment-from-form-using-phpmailer-and-php)

Comment: PS Do not update your question with answers from the question. Keep the original issue as it is. Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

You're missing one fundamental thing: you have not set the encoding type of the form. The default encoding will not work with files, so `$_FILES` will be empty, and consequently functions like `move_uploaded_file` will fail because there is no file to move, not because you have got the path or permissions wrong (though you can do that too!). Your form tag should be:

```
<form method="POST" action="testmail2.php" id="myform" class="fs-form fs-form-full" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">
```

Aside from that, base your code on [the file upload example provided with PHPMailer](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps).

Comment: I now get the following error: Could not access file: /upload/text-upload.pdf

Answer (score 2):

`$filename` should be an absolute filepath on your server, not a relative path as you have a leading dot which can screw up a lot of things `./` ...

You have:

```
 $filename = "./upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

What you should have is:

```
 move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],$_SERVER['Document_root']."/path/to/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
 ...
 $filename = $_SERVER['Document_root']."/path/to/upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

you should be using the PHPMailer error reporter (`$mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;`) to check this sort of things, as well as [reading your own PHP error messages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5127838/where-does-php-store-the-error-log-php-5-apache-fastcgi-and-cpanel). Also you should [follow the examples](https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/blob/master/examples/send_file_upload.phps) set in the github.

Comment: i will make code change as suggested, Do i need to make any change to line 26? `move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"./upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);`

Comment: Yes. `./` is a relative file path. you should be using an absolute file path

Comment: No file is being uploaded to the folder in the directory , even after making your suggested changes

Comment: So what does your PHPMailer error reporting tell you?

Comment: Could not access file: /upload/

Comment: @richag so that's your issue. As I said in my answer, I would suggest giving PHPMailer the absolute filepath to the file you want to attach.

Comment: sorry maybe you are miss understanding, this is a user contact form, where they upload their OWN file, and then I want the file attached to the email ...

Comment: @richag `Could not access file: /upload/` this means PHPMailer can't access the file that was uploaded. This is a server access problem not the issue with the person who has uploaded their file .

Comment: When I go to the directory , folder upload , it is empty, suggesting that the file being attached is not actually uploading to the directory folder 'upload'

Comment: @richag right, so then what does your PHP error log say about file uploading? ie your `move_uploaded_file` command?

Comment: @richag there are lots of Stack Overflow Q&A about file upload errors: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550972/php-cant-upload-files-to-server

Comment: @Matin, I enabled $mail->SMTPDebug = SMTP::DEBUG_SERVER;

I get no error besides Could not access file ... form the logs, it looks like it is not even trying to upload the attached file.

Answer (score 1):

You might try the `addStringAttachment()` method instead

Despite of its name, it does not work with text files only, but with any kind of file

Please refer to the following code snippet

```php
if (is_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"])) {
    $filename = $_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"];
    $handle = fopen($filename, "r");
    $contents = fread($handle, filesize($filename));
    fclose($handle);
    $mail->addStringAttachment($contents, $filename);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue

```
move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"],"upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
$filename = "upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
```

Thank you to everyone who assisted