# Using Curl to upload file to a PHP and get an "unable to move" error

Tags: php, powershell, curl, file-upload

I'd like set a simple HTTP service (with PHP) to receive files from another computer with Linux curl and Windows Powershell. I have read internet resource, including [PHP can't upload files to server?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9550972/php-cant-upload-files-to-server) and [Using cURL to upload POST data with files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12667797/using-curl-to-upload-post-data-with-files). These posts help me with parameters issues but not all.

here is my code (refer to [here](https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_file_upload.asp))

```php
<?php
$target_dir = "uploads/";
$target_file = $target_dir . basename($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"]);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES["fileToUpload"]["tmp_name"], $target_file)) {
echo "The file ". htmlspecialchars( basename( $_FILES["fileToUpload"]["name"])). " has been uploaded.";
} else {
echo "Sorry, there was an error uploading your file.";
}
?>
```

and here is the command that I used and got error response.

```bash
# bash
curl -X POST -F "id=fileToUpload" -F "fileToUpload=@null.txt" http://127.0.0.1/upload.php
```

Here is the /var/apache2/error.log

```
[Sun Aug 27 05:13:13.392185 2023] [php7:warn] [pid 77733] [client 127.0.0.1:54732] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(uploads/null.txt): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 5
[Sun Aug 27 05:13:13.392251 2023] [php7:warn] [pid 77733] [client 127.0.0.1:54732] PHP Warning:  move_uploaded_file(): Unable to move '/tmp/phpynhUuv' to 'uploads/null.txt' in /var/www/html/upload.php on line 5
```

the uploads status

```
$ ll   
> total 8
> drwxr-xr-x 2 root     root     4096 Aug 27 05:08 html
> drwxrwxrwx 2 www-data www-data 4096 Jun  2 22:38 uploads
```

Can anyone tell what's wrong with my code? Any opinions will be appreciated.

P.S. Thanks[ADyson](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5947043/adyson)  and [hanshenrik](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1067003/hanshenrik) generous guidance. This problem is caused in two aspects: (1) use -F for curl command and (2) correct the PHP path to fit my folder setting.

Comment: According that post, the ans is to apply -F. I'd tried like this `curl -X POST -F "file=@null.txt" http://127.0.0.1/upload.php` and got the same error. But still thanks for your reply.

Comment: What error did you get from the curl command? Are there any errors on the php side too (e.g. in log files)?

Comment: Thanks for reminding, I should have noticed this. I just read the /var/log/apache2/error.log and get some interesting hint. I'll work by myself first to see I can get it done.

Comment: Thanks. `-F "id=fileToUpload"`...this doesn't look like a filename from your device

Comment: Also your php code needs to check `$_FILES["fileToUpload"]["error"]` before attempting to use move_uploaded_file, to validate that it correctly received a file. See https://www.php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php

Comment: Are your php files stored in the `html` folder? If so then `uploads` is not a subfolder of that, so your path is wrong.  Try `$target_dir = "../uploads/";` instead.

Comment: Wow, you are amazing. It's indeed caused by the path error. You save my day, very thanks a lot.

Comment: No problem. Read https://phpdelusions.net/articles/paths for discussion on how to use paths correctly and get it right reliably

Answer (score 0):

`-d` sends the data with `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` format, which PHP automatically parses into the `$_POST` superglobal, while your code tries to read the uploaded file from the `$_FILES` superglobal, which to the best of my knowledge, PHP only parses from `multipart/form-data`-requests, and to make curl send `multipart/form-data` requests, use `-F`

```
curl -F @null.txt http://127.0.0.1/upload.php
```

Comment: I apology for this terrible question, will notice to make my question clear next time. Also  thanks for the "-F" reminder, it is helpful with the parameter issue. But it seems I got other issues for me to work with to make it work as expected.

Comment: @CarltonChen for what it's worth, your question is much better now with the edits :) good job fixing it!